# Why do I get a deprecated conversion warning with string literals in one case but not another?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, pointers, string-literals

I am learning C++. In the program shown here, as far as I know, `str1` and `str2` store the addresses of first characters of each of the relevant strings:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    char str1[]="hello";
    char *str2="world";
    cout<<str1<<endl;
    cout<<str2<<endl;
}
```

However, `str1`is not giving any warnings, while with `str2` I get this warning:

```
warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
     char *str2="world";
```

What's different between these two declarations that causes the warning in the second case but not the first?

Comment: "str1 and str2 shall stores the address of first char of string". That's not true. `str1` stores a copy of entire the string itself. It does not store any "address". `str2`, on the other hand, indeed stores the address.

Comment: HI ANT, if a copy is stored in str1 where the other copy of "hello" will be stored? If we modify the str1 copy say str[0]='H', will this change affect the other copy?

Comment: The original `"hello"` is stored in static and non-modifiable memory. When you do `str[0] = 'H'` you modify the copy stored in `str1`. The original remains untouched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write

```
char str1[] = "hello";
```

you are saying "please make me an array of `char`s that holds the string `"hello"`, and please choose the size of the array `str1` to be the size of the string initializing it." This means that `str1` ends up storing its own unique copy of the string `"hello"`. The ultimate type of `str1` is `char[6]` - five for `hello` and one for the null terminator.

When you write

```
char *str2 = "world";
```

you are saying "please make me a pointer of type `char *` that points to the string literal `"world"`." The string literal `"world"` has type `const char[6]` - it's an array of six characters (five for `hello` and one for the null terminator), and importantly those characters are `const` and can't be modified. Since you're pointing at that array with a `char *` pointer, you're losing the `const` modifier, which means that you now (unsafely) have a non-`const` pointer to a `const` bit of data.

The reason that things are different here is that in the first case, you are getting a *copy* of the string `"hello"`, so the fact that your array isn't `const` isn't a problem. In the second case, you are not getting a copy of `"hello"` and are instead getting a pointer to it, and since you're getting a pointer to it there's a concern that modifying it could be a real problem.

Stated differently, in the first case, you're getting an honest-to-goodness array of six characters that have a copy of `hello` in them, so there's no problem if you then decide to go and mutate those characters. In the second case, you're getting a pointer to an array of six characters that you're not supposed to modify, but you're using a pointer that permits you to mutate things.

So why is it that `"world"` is a `const char[6]`? As an optimization on many systems, the compiler will only put one copy of `"world"` into the program and have all copies of the literal `"world"` point to the exact same string in memory. This is great, as long as you don't change the contents of that string. The C++ language enforces this by saying that those characters are `const`, so mutating them leads to undefined behavior. On some systems, that undefined behavior leads to things like "whoa, my string literal has the wrong value in it!," and in others it might just segfault.

Comment: Hello, this is a very good answer. May I know "hello" and "world" both considered as string literal? Or only "world" is considered as string literal (bcz it is assigned to char *) ?

Comment: Both “hello” and “world” are string literals. The difference here arises based on what you assign those literals to. In the first case, the assignment is treated as array initialization, so a a copy of the literal is made. In the second, it’s pointer initialization, so no copy is made.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to convert a string literal (with type const char*) to char*.

Comment: While this is true, I don't think it addresses the OP's question about why the first option doesn't work.